# Uploading Expo App to TestFlight Doesn't Load .env File

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo, testflight

I'm trying to upload my Expo React Native iPhone app to TestFlight but my .env files aren't being loaded. I use `eas build` to get the .ipa file, and use Transporter to load the app onto App Store Connect. However, when I open the build in TestFlight, the .env variables are not being loaded, so the app is useless. I know that using Xcode is one way to get around this, but I used VSCode, and my app is so large already that going back from Expo now is not really viable.

Answer (score 2):

when you create a new build via eas build, you have to load your env variables either in your expo projects secrets or into the eas.json file. That file would then look something like

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.6.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
      "MY_API_ROUTE": "www.1234.dev.com", 
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "env": {
        "MY_API_ROUTE": "www.1234.prod.com", 
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/